# Trying to map objects inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, map-function

I'm a beginner at webdev and I'm having a little problem with reactjs. I have an array of data about universities, like:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "UFSM",
    total: 17,
    filled: 12,
    approved: 10,
    reproved: 1,
    dropouts: 1,
    requests: 170,
    approved_requests: 120,
    disciplines: [{name: "engineering", value: 10}, {name:"biology", value: 20}, ...]
  }, 
  {...
    disciplines: [{name: "engineering", value: 7}, ....]
  },...]
```

I'm using the map function to map all their names into an array, like:

```
let data_name = props.data.map((data) => data.name);
```

Is it possible to use map to group into an array the value of disciplines with the same name from different universities? Having an output like:

```
data_engineering = ["10", "7", ...]
```

So that I could have all engineering related disciplines from different universities on the same array.

Comment: If you want to do a grouping, you should consider ```array.reduce()``` more

Comment: Can you provide some more objects in the array? to confirm how the data looks like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
  name: "UFSM",
  total: 17,
  filled: 12,
  approved: 10,
  reproved: 1,
  dropouts: 1,
  requests: 170,
  approved_requests: 120,
  disciplines: [{
    name: "engineering",
    value: 10
  }, {
    name: "biology",
    value: 20
  }]
}, {
  name: "ABCD",
  total: 17,
  filled: 12,
  approved: 10,
  reproved: 1,
  dropouts: 1,
  requests: 170,
  approved_requests: 120,
  disciplines: [{
    name: "engineering",
    value: 4
  }, {
    name: "biology",
    value: 5
  }]
}, {
  name: "EFGH",
  total: 17,
  filled: 12,
  approved: 10,
  reproved: 1,
  dropouts: 1,
  requests: 170,
  approved_requests: 120,
  disciplines: [{
    name: "engineering",
    value: 5
  }, {
    name: "biology",
    value: 9
  }]
}]

let result = {};

data.map((data) => data.disciplines).forEach((item, index) => {
  item.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!result[item.name]) {
      result[item.name] = []
    }
    result[item.name].push(item.value);
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array for a single discipline like `engineering`, you can do the following map:

```js
data_engineering =
  props.data.map((uni) => uni.disciplines.engineering);
```

This array will have an `undefined` value for a university that doesn't have an engineering value defined. But that is probably what you want, because it means the indices line up with the indices of `data_name`.

If you want to build such an array for all disciplines, you can do the following:

```js
const dataDiscipline = {};
// 1. Collect all disciplines from all universities
// by making them a key of dataDiscipline.
props.data.forEach((uni) =>
  uni.disciplines.forEach((discipline) =>
    dataDiscipline[discipline] = null
  )
);
// 2. Now build the discipline array for each discipline.
Object.keys(dataDiscipline).forEach((discipline) =>
  dataDiscipline[discipline] =
    props.data.map((uni) => uni.disciplines[discipline])
);
// You can now use e.g. dataDiscipline.engineering
```